# how to get user of current process

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Using the process defined in struct task_struct http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.30.5/include/linux/sched.h#L246 how do I get the current user? I have to check if the user is root. I apparently can't use getuid

Comment: What do you intend to do? Do you have any code you can show?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`task_uid`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.8/include/linux/cred.h#L323) to get the user id of the `task_struct`, or `task_euid` if that's what you happen to need.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getlogin_r()` function. It is defined in unistd.h and returns the username. Have a look at `man getlogin_r` for other options.

```
int getlogin_r(char *buf, size_t bufsize);
```

Comment: Not a bad answer for userspace but the kernel doesn't have access to `getlogin_r`.

Comment: I think the question was from inside the kernel point of view.

Answer (score 0):

ended up using a member variable uid_t uid, which I didn't see at first. Checked the version of linux I was using (old) and found it here: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.18/include/linux/sched.h#L246

sorry for the trouble